# How can I modify 'Name' attribute of an instance via the Amazon EC2 API?

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'd like to be able to create/modify the 'Name' attribute of an EC2 instance, ie, the field shown by 'Name' in the web UI.

[image: Amazon EC2 web UI]

I am quite comfortable spawning instances via the Amazon API, however [I cannot find any references to instance naming in the API reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xryq0.png). How can I create an instance with the Name attribute set, or modify the Name of an existing instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Name* attribute is just a regular tag, that happens to be available/used by default for many resources, including [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances.

Accordingly, you can change it e.g. via the [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) (ec2-create-tags, ec2-describe-tags, ec2-delete-tags), which facilitate the respective APIs in turn, see section [API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#Using_Tags_API) within [Using Tags](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) for more details:

> Summary of available API actions:
>
> - **CreateTags** — Adds a set of tags to a set of resources. **You also use this
>     to update a tag's value (overwrites the existing value).** *[emphasis mine]*
> - **DeleteTags** — Deletes a set of tags from a set of resources.
> - **DescribeTags** — Lists your tags, or just certain ones you specify.

These actions are further detailed in the [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud API Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html?r=7437) as usual:

- [CreateTags](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-CreateTags.html)
- [DescribeTags](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeTags.html)
- [DeleteTags](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DeleteTags.html)

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else: note that 'Name' must be uppercase to appear in the web console.